# Migration to CRM 2016: Unable to get property 'getPageData' of undefined or null reference

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

After migration from CRM 2013 to CRM 2016 (On Premise), we have error messages in the browser like:

- Unable to get property '**getPageData**' of undefined or null reference
- Unable to get property '**className**' of undefined or null reference
- Unable to get property '**firstChild**' of undefined or null reference

The error happens in components of CRM. Any idea, what the reason could be?

```html
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Unable to get property 'getPageData' of undefined or null reference</Message>
   <Line>2083</Line>
   <URL>/_static/form/formcontrols.js?ver=1804820318</URL>
   <PageURL>/form/page.aspx?lcid=1033&themeId=f499443d-2082-4938-8842-e7ee62de9a23&tstamp=197130723&updateTimeStamp=635905304768102438&userts=131002784247688030&ver=1804820318#etc=2&extraqs=%3fetc%3d2%26id%3d%257b7DE4DCC6-207F-E511-9528-005056A03927%257d&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&counter=1455804831411</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymousr:Unabletogetproperty'getPageData'ofundefinedornullreference</Function>
   <FunctionRaw>TypeError: Unable to get property 'getPageData' of undefined or null reference</FunctionRaw>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymousr:Unabletogetproperty'getPageData'ofundefinedornullreference</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try suggestion provided at the end of thread - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/190275/482107

When do errors occur?

Answer (score 2):

I' v had similar error [1] on 8.2.2.112 when pressing Next Stage on Business Process Flow. Much effort was put into debugging so wanted to document it somwhere.

### Rollup field

The error was caused by rollup fields that provides SUM for Money fields. The HTML generated by CRM and javascript function didn't match.

Guilty line is within `/_static/form/formcontrols.js` called on line 28871: 
`XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetNextSibling(this.get_controlValue().parentNode)))))).innerHTML = CrmEncodeDecode.CrmHtmlDecode((this.$5_1.$3_2).get_currencySymbol());`

This one returns null and it therefore spits error: `XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetNextSibling(this.get_controlValue().parentNode`

### Solution

- FIX 1: Enable "Use legacy form rendering" under System Settings
- OR Fix 2: Remove Currency rollup fields from form.
- OR Fix 3: Create non-rollup fields that get calculated with workflow or plugin.
- OR Fix 4: You may do some jQuery stuff and add some empty siblings which it -
  expects. Except it may show duplicate currency symbol (at least for EUR currency) - one as prefix the other one as suffix.
- OR Fix 5: Most undesirable way: patch that .js yourself if you're on-premises.

  Replace line 28871:

  ```
    XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetNextSibling(this.get_controlValue().parentNode)))))).innerHTML = CrmEncodeDecode.CrmHtmlDecode((this.$5_1.$3_2).get_currencySymbol());
  ```

  With:

  ```
  if (XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetNextSibling(this.get_controlValue().parentNode) !== null) {
      XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetFirstChild(XUI.Html.DomUtils.GetNextSibling(this.get_controlValue().parentNode)))))).innerHTML = CrmEncodeDecode.CrmHtmlDecode((this.$5_1.$3_2).get_currencySymbol());
  }
  ```

### [1] Error:

```
<ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null</Message>
   <Line>0</Line>
   <URL>/form/page.aspx?lcid=1033&themeId=2cf54f8a-be4d-477c-a1f5-29b894a487ca&tstamp=53798526&updateTimeStamp=636392540341784672&userts=131546192871874626&ver=-1991520363#etc=3&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d3%26etc%3d3%26id%3d%257b586C2C21-E8F8-E611-80F5-005056BD19EE%257d%26opened%3dgrid%26process%3dc9426a91-9fc0-4c2d-a21c-4b9d2a38a6d5%26processts%3d51389819%26rskey%3d%257b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003001%257d&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&rskey=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003001%7d&counter=1510145890205</URL>
   <PageURL>/form/page.aspx?lcid=1033&themeId=2cf54f8a-be4d-477c-a1f5-29b894a487ca&tstamp=53798526&updateTimeStamp=636392540341784672&userts=131546192871874626&ver=-1991520363#etc=3&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d3%26etc%3d3%26id%3d%257b586C2C21-E8F8-E611-80F5-005056BD19EE%257d%26opened%3dgrid%26process%3dc9426a91-9fc0-4c2d-a21c-4b9d2a38a6d5%26processts%3d51389819%26rskey%3d%257b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003001%257d&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&rskey=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003001%7d&counter=1510145890205</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(dirtyVisiblePropertyData){var$v_0=dirtyVisiblePropertyData.getKeys();for(var$v_1=0;$v_1<$v_0.length;$v_1++){var$v_2=$v_0[$v_1];if(IsNull(this.get_viewMap().get_item($v_2))){}else{try{this.get_viewMap().get_item($v_2).update(dirtyVisiblePropertyD</Function>
   <FunctionRaw>function (dirtyVisiblePropertyData) {
        var $v_0 = dirtyVisiblePropertyData.getKeys();
        for (var $v_1 = 0; $v_1 < $v_0.length; $v_1++) {
            var $v_2 = $v_0[$v_1];
            if (IsNull(this.get_viewMap().get_item($v_2))) {
    </FunctionRaw>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(dirtyVisiblePropertyData){var$v_0=dirtyVisiblePropertyData.getKeys();for(var$v_1=0;$v_1<$v_0.length;$v_1++){var$v_2=$v_0[$v_1];if(IsNull(this.get_viewMap().get_item($v_2))){}else{try{this.get_viewMap().get_item($v_2).update(dirtyVisiblePropertyData.get_item($v_2));}catch($v_3){Mscrm.CrmDebug.fail(String.format('ExceptionencounteredupdatingUIelement{0}:{1}',$v_2,$v_3.message));catchError($v_3.message,window.location.href,0,true);}}}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){if(this.$AV_1){var$v_0=this.$4h_1;this.$4h_1=new(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.TypedDictionary$1.$$(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PropertyBag))();this.ui.updateUI($v_0);}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){this.$7A_1++;var$v_0=null;if(!this.$AE_1){setPerformanceMarkerTimestamp(String.format('UIUpdate{0}StartTime',this.$7A_1));$v_0=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch(String.format('UIUpdate{0}',this.$7A_1));$v_0.start();}this.$8w_1=false;for(var$v_1=0;$v_1<this.$2F_1.length;$v_1++){var$v_2=this.$2F_1[$v_1];if(!IsNull($v_2)){$v_2.flushVisibilityChanges();}}if($v_0){$v_0.stop();setPerformanceMarkerTimestamp(String.format('UIUpdate{0}EndTime',this.$7A_1));}window.top.TurboFormLoadStartTime=null;}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){Mscrm.Performance.PerformanceMarkerManager.get_instance().addMarker('MDDEnd',1);try{var$v_0=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('PostOnLoadUIUpdate');$v_0.start();this.finishUIUpdate();$v_0.stop();}finally{this.$Ih_1();this.updateFormDirtyState();try{if(isOutlookHostedWindow()){getOutlookHostedWindow().handlePostOnLoad();}}catch($$e_1){}}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){var$v_0=Xrm.Internal.startMetricsStopwatch('HandlePostOnLoad');$v_0.start();if(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().$L_1===this){this.get_pidRequestManager().clearRecords();Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().handlePostOnLoad();var$v_1=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.getPageState();if(!IsNull($v_1)&&$v_1.formType!==7&&!$v_1.recordId.equals(Microsoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.Guid.get_empty())){Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageBootstrapper.requestSubGridData();}this.get_pidRequestManager().requestPidPtsWithLookupService();setAttributeInWindow('FormEntityLogicalName',(this.data.getEntity())?this.data.getEntity().getEntityName()||'':'');setAttributeInWindow('FormEntityTypeCode',(this.data.getEntity()&&!Mscrm.InternalUtilities.JSTypes.isNull(this.data.getEntity().getEntityTypeCode()))?this.data.getEntity().getEntityTypeCode().toString():'');if(!Mscrm.InternalUtilities.JSTypes.isNullOrEmptyString(window.CUSTOM_ETC_LIST)&&JSON.parse(window.CUSTOM_ETC_LIST).indexOf(this.data.getEntity().getEntityTypeCode())>-1){setAttributeInWindow('IsCustomEntity','true');}else{setAttributeInWindow('IsCustomEntity','false');}if(!IsNull(window.turboHeaderScriptIncludes)){if(this.scriptIncludesSearch(window.turboHeaderScriptIncludes,'/_static/cs/articlesearchribbon/articlesearchribbon.js')){Mscrm.CrmHeader.setScriptFileForTurboForm(Mscrm.CrmUri.create('/_static/CS/ArticleSearchRibbon/ArticleSearchRibbon.js'));}}Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().loadActionHubIframe();window.setTimeout(this.$$d_$Ff_1,15);if(!IsNull($v_1)&&$v_1.formType!==7){Mscrm.MetricsCollector.collectAndReportClientMetrics(2);}}else{Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.PageManager.get_instance().finishUIUpdate();}$v_0.stop();}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){returnb.apply(a,arguments)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(c,d){for(varb=0,e=a.length;b<e;b++)a[b](c,d)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(message){switch(message){case'TurboFormPostOnloadTimestamp':setPerformanceMarkerTimestamp('TurboFormPostOnloadTimestamp');Mscrm.Performance.PerformanceMarkerManager.get_instance().addMarker('TurboFormPostOnloadTimestamp',1);var$v_0=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.CustomScriptsManager.get_instance().$7d_1.getHandler(String.format('MessageEventFormat_{0}',message));if(!IsNull($v_0)){$v_0();window.pageLoadedCheckForNavigateApi=true;if(!IsNull(window.parent)&&!IsNull(window.parent.parent)){window.parent.pageLoadedCheckForNavigateApi=true;window.parent.parent.pageLoadedCheckForNavigateApi=true;}}break;case'ScriptsAreLoaded':if(Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.CustomScriptsManager.get_instance().$57_1){Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.CustomScriptsManager.get_instance().$57_1=false;}var$v_1=Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.CustomScriptsManager.get_instance().$7d_1.getHandler(String.format('ScriptsAreLoaded',message));if(!IsNull($v_1)){$v_1();}break;}}</Function>
    <Function>SendMessageToPageManager(message)</Function>
    <Function>RunHandlerInternal(method,parameters,executionContext,executeIfAvailableOnly)</Function>
    <Function>RunHandlers()</Function>
    <Function>OnScriptTagLoaded(url)</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){OnScriptTagLoaded(url);}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrii!

Removing a composite control in the header did the trick.

It seems to be a bug in CRM 2016, but our customers can live without this information in the header. All fine!

Kind regards,
Matthias